# Почему при разметке текста в Label Studio метка смещается вправо на один символ?

Tags: label, разметка, датасет

Выполняю разметку текста, но результат метки для некоторых (большинства) слов смещается вправо на один символ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел причину - увидел что в базе данных перед некоторыми строками стоит пробел. Очистил пробелы перед строками и теперь метки ставятся без смещения